# Laravel Response::json failing

Tags: json, laravel, response

I'm trying to send a JSON Response from the server by passing an array to Response::json() but I keep getting the UTF-8 Invalid Argument in vendor\laravel\ ... \jsonReponse.php At line 49

```
public function getAllForInbox() {

    $conn = SqlServerPdo::connect();

    $query = "Some Query";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);

    $success = $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    SqlServerPdo::disconnect();

    return Response::json($result);

}
```

Everything else works fine. I did a var_dump on $result. 
IS an array containing arrays of data. Each array being a row from the result.

The thing is .... It was working perfectly.... then I ran Composer Update ... and now it doesn't work anymore o.O ... could it be some error on the vendor/laravel folder???

In fact, I have a local development server running, and it works just fine, when I upload to the server currently hosting the App, it doesn't... could it be PHP???

this is and example $result var dump

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["numint"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "Sistel Helpdesk"
    ["priority"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["assignation"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tickets_open"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["tickets_with_conv"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
...
```

And 9 other results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably some non UTF-8 string in your database.

When the `Response::json()` tries to run - it fails because of non UTF8.

You need to cycle through your array and run `utf8_enconde()` on all the results before passing it to `Response::json()`

Comment: This throws an error => utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: got Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: iconv() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given

Comment: this my help you.... if I pass $result[0] ... which is the first array in the array.. it works

Comment: the problem is when I pass an array of arrays ... for some reason it doesn't like it

Comment: besides :p in my local server I have the same database, with the same records... and it works :P ...

Comment: yeah - but your local DB might be UTF8 - and your production server is not. Try $result[1], $result[2] etc in the json return - see which one causes the error.

Comment: p.s. try my updated answer again. Basically what you need to do is force the array to all be UTF8 - then the error will go away.

Comment: with the update answer, i get utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given .... also ... there is an extra ')' after $result)

Comment: ya, the problem is that some results are not UTF-8 ... I'll just have to make a cycle to transform them in UTF-8 ... ty ... I'll manage with the algoritm. Its just posting the anwser saying what is the cause of the problem.. post it and i'll mark it as correct